# Which is better for tax saving purposes whilst in a contract that is inside IR35: a limited company, or an umbrella?

Tags: taxes, income-tax, united-kingdom, limited-liability-company, contractor

I am about to take a job that is inside IR35. I have been trading via a limited company and all my contracts have been outside IR35 for the past 12 years.

I'm half way through my tax year and I would like to know if it would be better to bill via my limited company and my accountant calculates my PAYE for me and the limited pays me. Or, going through an umbrella company and leaving my limited company open for trade and possibly working a second contract that is still outside IR35.

I'm confused and the recruiter is telling me that if I go through my limited company, I will pay tax twice, once when the company that is inside IR35 and a second time when my limited company pays me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Get yourself a tax adviser who knows what they are doing. Or better, do whatever you can to get a position outside IR35. This will mess up all your tax planning.